# Not Able to Load All WP-QUERY result to JSON Encode in Custom Loop

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I am trying to pass wp-query result to a JSON output like this

```
$isready = "true";
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
      $html = '<div class="card px-0">';
        $html .='<div class="row p-1">';
           $html .='<div class="col-4 px-0">'.get_the_title() .'</div>';
        $html .='</div>';
      $html .='</div>'; 
     endwhile;
$response = ["html"=>$html, "isready"=>$isready];
header("Content-Type: application/json");
echo json_encode($response);
```

the problem is at the client side I am only getting one of the post while I have at least 6 custom post type

In the Js `.done()`  I have

```
$('#posts').html(data.html);
```

but as I said it is only adding one post to the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop resets $html every time and only gives you the last one as result.

You have:

```
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
  $html = '<div...
```

Make it:

```
$html = "";
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
  $html .= '<div....
```